# How would you create a protocol to access MongoDB with Rebol?

Tags: mongodb, rebol

Rebol has a standard [abstraction](http://www.rebol.com/docs/database.html) in dealing with databases but the documentation all pretty much relates to the now very old Rebol2.

What approach is required to write a protocol in Rebol3 to interface to MongoDB given that Rebol3 uses asynchronous tcp and the previously written documentation appears to be a synchronous approach?

Comment: https://github.com/onetom/rebol-red-sublime Rebol, Red and Red/System syntax highlighting for Sublime Text 2/3

Comment: I'll again cite [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol), and [the (new) forum](https://forum.rebol.info) as good places to go for open-ended questions that may not be a fit for StackOverflow proper...

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/)

`The MongoDB Wire Protocol is a simple socket-based, request-response style protocol. Clients communicate with the database server through a regular TCP/IP socket.`

Rebol is quite capable of handling such protocols and they are easy enough for users to write.  You can look at examples such as the [SMTP](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gchiu/Rebol3/master/protocols/prot-smtp.reb) and [POP3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gchiu/Rebol3/master/protocols/prot-pop3.reb) ones to see how the async mode is transformed to sync.

MongoDB also uses a binary format of JSON called [BSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438280/what-is-bson-and-exactly-how-is-it-different-from-json) and Rebol has [libraries](https://github.com/r3n/renclib/blob/master/modules/json.reb) already dealing with JSON which is not surprising given that Rebol was one of the inspirations for JSON.

Comment: it may be simple for a rebol guru but not for others like the guy above or me :) So I'll give it up on Rebol for this one and take on NodeJs instead.