# Difference between regular JSON storage and BSON (binary JSON)?

Tags: json, binary-data, bson

I am reading "[Designing Data Intensive Applications](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/designing-data-intensive-applications/9781491903063/)". It is mentioned that you can extend JSON encoding with binary encoding (using libraries like [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html)).

I am getting a little confused because everything gets encoded down to binary to be sent across the network, right? I mean: even every character in JSON is ultimately stored as 0s and 1s (binary).

What is the difference then? It will be great if one could elaborate with an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is BSON and exactly how is it different from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438280/what-is-bson-and-exactly-how-is-it-different-from-json)

Comment: No, the most well-known non-binary network protocol in use is HTTP, being text oriented. It's like arguing that this very text must be binary at some point, but then again you're able to read it right away. Numbers in texts don't magically get stored in 32bit Integers, but instead remain as text and as `945534` then consume 6 (UTF-8/ASCII) or 12 (UTF-16) or 24 (UTF-32) instead of 4 bytes.